# installing a program via remote desktop win server 2003

Tags: installation, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

I have installed a small lite c# program I developed on a windows 2003 server. I did this via remote desktop. Now when I login to the server I can't find it in task manager (it should be always running). Anyone know why this is failing? Can't I install long running desktop apps via remote desktop unless its a windows service?

Note: this is not a windows service, it's a simple desktop program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your case or not, but I had the same experience but my problem was opening the task manager of my own computer instead of the remote one. Do you open the task manager via calling taskman.exe from the remote computer command prompt?

other option: Do you log off the server when disconnecting? If your program is not a service, it will be closed on logging off.

Comment: I login with a user account from the administrators group so I'm authorized to do everything. Then I do the installation. Then I log of.

Comment: As I told you, by logging of the server, all non-service programs will be closed. So, when you login again, you need to raunch it again manually, or put it in the your account startup items.